# How to integrate barcode scanner into glass app

Tags: android, google-glass, zxing, google-gdk

I have been struggeling with that topic for some time and have no idea how to process further. For first release I don't need even QR code, just simple one.
My glass API is XE22.
I have already tried to use https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner, I changed screen resolution, but seems just camera is turning on.
When I install apk https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases/tag/BSGlass-0.2.1 I have the same situation, camera is turning on, but there is no box to scan barcode.
Only app which is working for me is BarcodeEye, but have no idea how to integrate it with my app. When used Intent I get the same message as @nagendra in [BarCodeEye QR Cocde Scanner implementation in my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983145/barcodeeye-qr-cocde-scanner-implementation-in-my-application) , but when try to use tip from @swooby I get message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aa00403.barcodetest/com.example.aa00403.barcodetest.Main}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.github.barcodeeye.SCAN flg=0x4080000 pkg=com.github.barcodeeye (has extras) }
```

I would be greatefull for any hint, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to make a barcode scanning application. I tested ZXing and barcodeEye, but I couldn't make them work either.

I found a library that works well made by [scandit](http://www.scandit.com).

The SDK is not free for commercial use, but there is a community plan you can use to trial the library without time-limit. This free version is limited to QR codes and UPC/Ean though.

I'm actually currently making an app that scans a barcode, looks up the product in the Amazon API, then send the result to a Trello list.
Source is at [github](https://github.com/sylvainemery/GlassWishList). If you just need to scan, look at the ScanActivity.

I hope this will help you! Also, I'm absolutely not an Android/Glass expert developer, so fell free to challenge my code :-)

Disclaimer: I don't work for scandit nor do I know anybody working there.

Answer (score 0):

I have got ZXing working (which is what barcode eyes is based on). But it was a total hack, I didn't so much integrate ZXing with my app as integrate my app into the ZXing sample android app, so I still have all the ZXing source in my project.
However ZXing is not good at scanning small barcodes on glass, and by small I mean, any size you'd ever find on an actual product. It works with really big barcodes (around 10-15cm long) and works fairly well with QR codes.

But Scandit does work way better, as Sylvain mentioned it is paid for commercial but is so much easier and cleaner to integrate and the community edition is free.  I'd suggest giving that a try.